# Using NSURL sendSynchronousRequest and having no response from the server using Adhoc build on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, testflight

So I have an app that send a synchronous request to my remote server and all goes right running it from xcode. The question is that when I archive the app and send it to TestFlight, the tester receive no response, making the same request. I'm using the xcode's Devices window to see the log within the device with the Adhoc build and it gives me a empty object coming from the server. I have also made the request from a browser's web client to certify there is no error on the server.  Here goes the code:

```
-(NSDictionary *)postData:(NSString *)data toUrl:(NSString *)url
{
    if( nil == url || nil == data ){ return nil; }
    NSString *fullUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self baseUrl], url];

    NSURL * serviceUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:fullUrl];
    NSMutableData *dados = [NSMutableData data];

    [dados appendData: [data dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest * serviceRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
    [serviceRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPBody:dados];

    NSHTTPURLResponse * serviceResponse;
    NSError * serviceError;
    NSData *dataResponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest
                                             returningResponse:&serviceResponse
                                                         error:&serviceError];

    NSString *status = [self statusFamily:serviceResponse.statusCode];
    NSDictionary *dataFromResponse = [[QMParser sharedParser] dataToDictionary:dataResponse];

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:serviceResponse, @"response",
                                                           status, @"status",
                                                 dataFromResponse, @"data", nil];
}
```

Comment: where do you use the returned dictionary ??

Comment: Inside the other method, the one that make the request.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, due to the provisioning profile. I solved the problem by setting automatically the provisioning profile in Xcode (Go to Project Settings -> Build Settings -> Code Signing).

[image: Code signing - Provisioning profile automatic]

I think TestFlight require new AdHoc provisioning profile. Before this fix the app crashes in every device not included in the AdHoc provisioning profile when the application makes a a generic http request.

If that doesn't work try to delete all the prov profile and let xcode to recreate them.